# Killing linux process from java doesn't work in Runnable JAR

Tags: java, linux, process, terminal

In my programm, I start a gnome-terminal and execute a programm in it. When that programm finished running a simulation, I kill the process and restart it again. Killing it is important because otherwize not all resources are released, even after the simulation stopped (and this makes HeapSpaceError more likely).

The method to start the process looks like this:

```
private void startNeSSiAndWait(int i) {

    System.out.println("OS is " + os);
    // if some unix system - we assume there is a gnome-terminal
    if(os.contains("nix") || os.contains("nux") || os.contains("aix")){

        String[] cmds = {"gnome-terminal", "-x" ,"bash", "-c", "cd '" + nessiPath + "'; export JAVA_HOME="+javaHome +"; ./nessi2.sh"};
        try {
            nessiProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds); // nessiProcess is an instance of Process

            Thread.sleep(5000); // wait till programm is ready
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error in executing proces..");
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }catch(InterruptedException ex){
            System.err.println("Error in sleeping..");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else if(os.contains("win")){
       ...
    }

}
```

The method to kill the process is this one:

```
private void killNeSSiAndWait(){

    nessiProcess.destroy();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error in sleeping..");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("destroyed");
}
```

These methods work fine as long as I start it from NetBeans. But as soon as I export it as a Runnable JAR, killing the process doesn't work.

I'm running it on Ubuntu 12.10 32Bit machine with Java 6.

What might be the reason for it not to work as a Runnable JAR?

**Edit**:
There are no errors as an output. The terminal just continues executing nessi2.sh and ignores the `nessiProcess.destroy()`.

NeSSi2 is a simulator, developed at DAI-Laboratories, for further information, see [here](http://www.nessi2.de/). We are only using the backend. The only visible output of nessi-backend is via the terminal.
I know that nessi is still running, because:

- the terminal is still running - it kills itself when there are no more processes running in it
- the simulation restarts without restarting nessi (but this is **not** what I want)

Since we are only using the backend and you will only see some text in a terminal, I think there is no reason for posting a screenshot. If anybody still likes to see it, I can post a screenshot, though.

We are using NeSSi2 to make some network-simulations. For this, my programm first starts the backend, then starts simulation and waits till the simulation is finished. When the simulation is finished, the programm kills NeSSi2, restarts it and starts another simulation. This procedure runs in a loop for several times.

Comment: What are you trying to kill; `nessi2.sh`?

Comment: Yes. And then the terminal automatically closes.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. Why do you use gnome-terminal and 2. How do you know that nessi2 is still running? It would be useful to know what nessi does and see the output of `ps`

Comment: I made some edits. Why shouldn't I use gnome-terminal? The programm will only run on several machines - it's not our goal to have it runnable on all linux devices.

Comment: Maybe the way you start the runnable jar doesn't grant you all the privilegs you need to kill processes.

Comment: Ok.. That works, thanks! I really didn't think that might be the problem (therefore, I didn't test). And I have no idea, why it is a problem. I now started the program as sudo. But I never started NetBeans as sudo. And I believe that the process I create is from *my* account, because I have a costumized terminal. And when nessi is started, it is started in a costumized terminal.. Do you have any idea why it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sir RotN has guessed, the problem was due to user privilegs. I still don't know why, but his comment solved my problem.
Thanks for that.